# How load data from mySql in an HTML button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-applications

I want to load data from my MySql database and put one field of this database into the text of a button :

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username   = "prova";
  $password   = "";
  $dbname     = "prova";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql    = "SELECT nomeCantiere,codiceCommessa,indirizzoCantiere FROM Cantiere";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "nomeCantiere: " . $row["nomeCantiere"] . " - codieCommessa: " . $row["codieCommessa"] . " - indirizzoCantiere" . $row["indirizzoCantiere"] . "<br>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

I'm a beginner with this type of programming.

For now I have managed to do is generate a simple `"echo"`.

How can I automatically generate buttons with a `value="nomeCantiere"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done with the code. You just need to add the value here:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //// Look at this line ////
    echo '<input type="button" value="' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '" />';
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

The above will generate a few rows of buttons. If that's what you would need. `:)`

Comment: Ha ha... Is that helpful? @NarcosZTK_10

Comment: @NarcosZTK_10 Glad that you got it solved. Have a nice day. Will wait for 5 mins... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can echo html tags in php
ie.

```
echo "<button>". $row["nomeCantiere"] ."</button>"
```

or

```
echo "<input type='button' value='". $row["nomeCantiere"] ."'/>"
```

Comment: `<input type="button">` not a `<button>`!

Comment: @RiggsFolly isn't it the same ? Or this is because NarcosZTK_10's code was an <input type="button"> ?

Comment: Because the OP's code uses an `<input type="button">`

Comment: @RiggsFolly is it because of the submit issue? we can specify type=button in <button> right